# Why some of the ren'youkeis (masu stem forms) have different meanings when they form compound verbs?

Tags: words, compound-verbs

The following are taken from the 新明解国語辞書.

> **取り** [接頭語的に]　動詞に冠し、「十分に、慎重に、確実に」などの意を加える。「ーあつかう・ーつくろう・ー調べる」
>
> **打ち** 動詞の上に冠して、「ちょっと・すっかり・よく」などの意を表わす。「ー見る・ー明ける・ー沈む・ー興ずる・ー砕く」

and there are more examples like this. However, the corresponding verbs 「取る」「打つ」 do not seem to have these meanings, nor do the kanjis (as I understand it from a native Chinese speaker's perspective).

So my question is, how do these stem forms acquire these meanings?

To elaborate, is it related to the history (classical Japanese perhaps) or how Japanese people understand these things? Do native Japanese consider 取る+調べる to naturally have the meaning of 取り調べる, or is the 取り in 取り調べる understood as "something different" as well by native speakers? How to make the difference more easy to understand for Japanese learners?

Personally I found it very confusing when I attempted to get the meaning of 取り調べる from 取る+調べる (or 取って調べる). A even worse case is attempting to get the meaning of 打ち明ける from 打って明ける which does not seem to be used at all in Japanese according to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E6%89%93%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%98%8E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%22). It didn't seem clear to me until I saw the quotes above and learnt that they can mean something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問者はN1取得者なので日本語で回答します。

（１）質問者が挙げた接頭辞/接頭語である「取り」と「打ち」との組み合わせでできる単語に関してどのように理解して使用しているかだけを述べます。
例えば「取り調べる」に関しては、「取る＋調べる」としてではなく、「取り調べる」という一つの単語として意味を理解しています。その理解の中には、「取る」や「調べる」という個々の意味を統合するような思考過程は何ら存在しない。
従って、新明解国語辞書が、「取り」に対して、 [接頭語的に]　動詞に冠し、「十分に、慎重に、確実に」などの意を加える。と記述しているのは、「調べる」と「取り調べる」との差を分析的に記述しているだけで、「取り」に、このような意味合いがあることは、「取り調べる」という単語を使用する、あるいは読み書きするときに実際には考えていない。

（２）質問者への完全な回答にはなりませんが、関連資料が[ここ](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/contentscinii_20180201234547.pdf?id=ART0008984963)にあります。
関係する部分を以下に引用します。

> 『国語学大辞典』（551 ページ）が「接辞と複合語要素とは、本来、一つづきのものと考えられる」と指摘しているように、接頭辞と複合語前半要素の境界は明確ではない。以下に同書から引用する。（3）接頭語の「[うち]{LL}明ける」「[さし]{LL}出す」「[ひっ]{LL}越す」「[かっ]{LL}払う」「[つん]{LL}のめる」などはもと動詞の連用形からきたものである… ［中略］ …コ＋ タカイ〉コダカイ、ヒキ＋ コス〉ヒッコスのように連濁その他の音韻変化を起こしたりする点も、複合語の場合と同様であって、その間に明確な一線を画することはむずかしい。たとえば、同一の「うちよせる」という語において、波が岸を打ってよせてくるとか、馬に乗って近づくとかという意味の場合には、この「うち」に実質的意味があって、複合語の前項としなければならないが、「敵がうちよせる」などという場合には「うち語らう」「うち見る」などと見比べて、単に強調のニュアンスを添える「うち」だと考えれば、接頭語ということになる。
>   このように接頭辞と複合語前項の境界を確定することは、日本語形態論固有の課題であると考えられる。あるいは、このような境界を画定する必要はないという論も一つの考え方として成り立つであろう。

Comment: `質問者はN1取得者なので日本語で回答します。` でも・・他の読者がみんなそうとは限らないですよね・・って日本語でコメントしてる私も人のこと言えんけど

Comment: 「…との差を分析的に記述している**だけ**で。」そうですね。あなたが言った通り、この辞書の記述はそういうふうで読めば理解しやすいです。接頭辞と複合語前項の境界を画定するのは難しいことも初めて聞きました。接頭辞に関する論文があったらきっと役に立つと思います。いろいろ勉強しました、誠にありがとうございます。